# How to send mail using nodemailer and Zoho mail?

Tags: javascript, node.js, email

I'm trying to setup ZOHO mail with Nodemailer. The mail is configured correctly and I'm using following code to send the mail, but still getting error in sending mail:

```
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

let from = `Company Name <contact@company.com>`

let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    // host: "smtp-mail.gmail.com",
    host: 'smtp.zoho.com',
    port: 465,
    secure: true,
    auth: {
        user: "contact@company.com",
        pass: "mypassword"
    }
});

// Mail response to User
        const mailResponse = {
            from: from,
            to: `userName`,
            subject: " Thanks For Connecting With Company Name",
            html: // mail body
}


 try {
            
            await transporter.sendMail(mailResponse);

            res.status(200).json({ message: "Message Sent" });
        } catch (err) {
            res.status(400).json({ message: "Unexpected Error!!! Please try again" });
        }
```

Please let me know how can I fix this issue. i have tried every possible solution given on website.

Comment: what's the error ?

Comment: I am getting catch block error - "Unexpected Error!!! Please try again"

Comment: can you please add "console.log(err)" before the "res.status(400).json({ message: "Unexpected Error!!! Please try again" });" line and start again the script and post the logged error here ?

Comment: I am getting - Invalid login: 535 Authentication Failed.
But I have generated password and used that password for email. Then why this error?

Comment: please make sure that the email is the exact same email on ZOHO, it seems like it's pretty known error (https://help.zoho.com/portal/en/community/topic/zoho-nodemailer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this -

```
service: "gmail",
host: "smtp.gmail.com",
auth: {
    user: "username@company.com",
    pass: "yourpassword"
}
```

At the place of `user` put your email and in `pass` but your password or you can get these from env to be safe.